# How do you pick variable substitutions in recurrence relations?

Tags: math, recurrence

In our Data Structures class we are learning how to solve recurrence relations in 1 variable. Unfortunately some things seem to come "out of the blue".

For example, some exercises already tell you how to substitute the variable n:

Compute T(n) for n = 2^k

- T(n) = a for n =< 2
- T(n) = 8T(n/2) + bn^2 (a and b are > 0)

But some exercises just give you the T(n) without providing a replacement for the variable n:

- T(n) = 1 n =<1
- T(n) = 2T(n/4) + sqrt(n)

I used the iterative method and arrived to the right answer: sqrt(n) + (1/2) * sqrt(n) * Log(n).

But when the professor explained she started by saying: "Let n = 4^k", which is what I mean by "out of the blue". Using that fact the answer is simpler to obtain.

But how is the student supposed to come up with that?

This is another example:

- T(n) = 1 n =<1
- T(n) = 2T( (n-1)/2 ) + n

Here I started again with the iterative method but I can't reach a definitive answer, it looks more complex that way. 
After 3 iterative steps I arrived to this:

1. T(n) = 4T( (n-2)/4 ) + 2n - 1
2. T(n) = 8T( (n-3)/8 ) + 3n - 3
3. T(n) = 16T( (n-4)/16 ) + 4n - 6

I am inclined to say T(i) = 2^i * T( (n-i)/2^i ) + i*n - ? This last part I can't figure out, maybe I made a mistake.

However in the answer she provides she starts again with another substitution: Let n = (2^k) -1. I don’t see where this comes from - why would I do this? What is the logic behind that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all of these cases, these substitutions are reasonable because they rewrite the recurrence as one of the form S(k) = aS(k - 1) + f(k). These recurrences are often easier to solve than other recurrences because they define S(k) purely in terms of S(k - 1).

Let's do some examples to see how this works. Consider this recurrence:

> T(n) = 1 (if n ≤ 1)
>
> T(n) = 2T(n/4) + sqrt(n) (otherwise)

Here, the size of the problem shrinks by a factor of four on each iteration. Therefore, if the input is a perfect power of four, then the input will shrink from size 4<sup>k</sup> to 4<sup>k-1</sup>, from 4<sup>k-1</sup> to 4<sup>k-2</sup>, etc. until the recursion bottoms out. If we make this substitution and let S(k) = T(4<sup>k</sup>), then we get hat

> S(0) = 1
>
> S(k) = 2S(k - 1) + 2<sup>k</sup>

This is now a recurrence relation where S(k) is defined in terms of S(k - 1), which can make the recurrence easier to solve.

Let's look at your original recurrence:

> T(n) = a (for n ≤ 2)
>
> T(n) = 8T(n/2) + bn<sup>2</sup>

Notice that the recursive step divides n by two. If n is a perfect power of two, then the recursive step considers the power of two that comes right before n. Letting S(k) = T(2<sup>k</sup>) gives

> S(k) = a (for k ≤ 1)
>
> S(k) = 8S(k - 1) + b2<sup>2k</sup>

Notice how that S(k) is defined in terms of S(k - 1), which is a much easier recurrence to solve. The choice of powers of two was "natural" here because it made the recursive step talk purely about the previous value of S and not some arbitrarily smaller value of S.

Now, look at the last recurrence:

> T(n) = 1 (n ≤ 1)
>
> T(n) = 2T( (n-1)/2 ) + n

We'd like to make some substitution k = f(n) such that T(f(n)) = 2T(f(n) - 1) + n. The question is how to do that.

With some trial and error, we get that setting f(n) = 2<sup>n</sup> - 1 fits the bill, since

> (f(n) - 1) / 2 = ((2<sup>n</sup> - 1) - 1) / 2 = (2<sup>n</sup> - 2) / 2 = 2<sup>n-1</sup> - 1 = f(n) - 1

Therefore, letting k = 2<sup>n</sup> - 1 and setting S(k) = T(2<sup>n</sup> - 1), we get

> S(n) = 1 (if n ≤ 1)
>
> S(n) = 2S(n - 1) + 2<sup>n</sup> - 1

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you a lot, so it seems that the purpose is to re-write it as S(k) = aS(k - 1) + f(k) but the substitution varies case by case, , at least now I have a better grasp.